# Jenkins pipeline script from fixed branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to create a job (via job dsl plugin) that is executed whenever a push happens to any branch, but the script that gets executed should be from a fixed branch.

```
pipelineJob('Job') {
        
    triggers {
        githubPush()
    }

    definition {
        cpsScm {
            lightweight(true)
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        url('<giturl>')
                        credentials('<credentials>')
                        branches("*/*")
                    }
                }
            scriptPath('job.gdsl')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the current job dsl definition of the job. While the triggering works, the jobs looks for the job.gdsl in the branch that triggered the build. But the job.gdsl should always be executed on the main branch, no matter from which branch push the build was triggered.

```
extensions {
    localBranch('master')
}
```

Sets master to the commit that triggered the job, which is not what i want. Setting the branch property doesn't work either because than the job is only triggered for the given branch.

The goal is to update a reference repo as soon as a commit is pushed to any branch. Maybe someone has an other solution for that. The reference repo tutorials always use a simple cron the execute the job, which kind of sucks because it polls github every X minutes.